# Set column value from running total in a vectorized way

Tags: pandas

I've read tons of questions and answers but I can't find a way to accomplish this, if it's even possible.

Consider this dataframe:

| Date | Name | N | Buy | Sell | Ret | Size | Profit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 100000 |
| 2023-02-01 | QQQ | 3 | 294.41 | 300.92 | 0.022112 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-01 | AMZN | 3 | 102.53 | 105.15 | 0.025554 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-01 | TXN | 3 | 177 | 172.1 | -0.02768 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-02 | AAPL | 2 | 148.9 | 150.82 | 0.012895 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-02 | MSFT | 2 | 258.82 | 264.6 | 0.022332 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-03 | QQQ | 2 | 304.94 | 306.18 | 0.004066 |  |  |  |
| 2023-02-03 | MSFT | 2 | 259.54 | 258.35 | -0.00459 |  |  |  |

I need to fill it up so that the last 3 columns look like this:

| Date | Name | N | Buy | Sell | Ret | Quantity | Profit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 100000 |
| 2023-02-01 | QQQ | 3 | 294.41 | 300.92 | 0.022112 | 113.2208 | 737.0685 | 100737.1 |
| 2023-02-01 | AMZN | 3 | 102.53 | 105.15 | 0.025554 | 327.5044 | 858.0624 | 101595.1 |
| 2023-02-01 | TXN | 3 | 177 | 172.1 | -0.02768 | 191.3279 | -937.507 | 100657.6 |
| 2023-02-02 | AAPL | 2 | 148.9 | 150.82 | 0.012895 | 338.0041 | 648.9725 | 101306.6 |
| 2023-02-02 | MSFT | 2 | 258.82 | 264.6 | 0.022332 | 195.7086 | 1131.195 | 102437.8 |
| 2023-02-03 | QQQ | 2 | 304.94 | 306.18 | 0.004066 | 167.9638 | 208.2735 | 102646.1 |
| 2023-02-03 | MSFT | 2 | 259.54 | 258.35 | -0.00459 | 197.7461 | -235.318 | 102410.7 |

`N` is the number of transactions for that date;

`Ret` is the arithmetic return of `Buy` and `Sell`;

`Quantity` =  previous `Balance` / `Buy` / `N`;

`Profit` = `Quantity` * `Ret` * `Buy`

`Balance`= previous `Balance` + `Profit`

I can't figure out how to calculate `Quantity` and `Balance` without a loop, since they are interdependent. My best guess is the following, but doesn't work:

```
    best['Balance'] = 0
    best['Balance'].iloc[0] = 100000

    best['Quantity'] = (best['Balance'].shift(1) / best['N']).round(0)

    # profit of each trade
    best['Profit'] = best['Quantity'] * (best['Sell'] - best['Buy'])

    best['Balance'] = best['Balance'].shift(1) + best['Profit']
```

Any pointers?

Thanks a lot to all!

Comment: What is `Size` (and `Balance`)?

Comment: why did you reset the Balance to `0` (`best['Balance'] = 0`) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest. I think now the last third columns are the expected result.

Comment: @Corralien Size is quantity (made the correction) and Balance is the running total of the available cash.

Comment: @Corralien Right, that's the desired result! I realize now I didn't explain it properly.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Do you think it's possible at all to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple columns within the same [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) where one of the columns depends on another one defined within the same assign:

```
df.assign(Quantity=(df['Balance'].shift(1) / df['N']).round(0),
          Profit=lambda x: x['Quantity'] * (x['Sell'] - x['Buy']),
          Balance=lambda x: x['Balance'].shift(1) + x['Profit'])
```

---

```
          Date   Name    N     Buy    Sell       Ret  Quantity     Profit    Balance
0  2023-01-31     NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
1  2023-02-01    QQQ   3.0  294.41  300.92  0.022112   33333.0  216997.83  316997.83
2  2023-02-01   AMZN   3.0  102.53  105.15  0.025554   33579.0   87976.98  188714.08
3  2023-02-01    TXN   3.0  177.00  172.10 -0.027680   33865.0 -165938.50  -64343.40
4  2023-02-02   AAPL   2.0  148.90  150.82  0.012895   50329.0   96631.68  197289.28
5  2023-02-02   MSFT   2.0  258.82  264.60  0.022332   50653.0  292774.34  394080.94
6  2023-02-03    QQQ   2.0  304.94  306.18  0.004066   51219.0   63511.56  165949.36
7  2023-02-03   MSFT   2.0  259.54  258.35 -0.004590   51323.0  -61074.37   41571.73
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't understand the last column: the balance should be increasing if the profit is positive. How does it become 188,714.08 in row 2? It should be 404,974.81.

Comment: Sorry what's the starting df to generate this result? I can't replicate it...

Comment: @chris, the input df was taken precisely from your question/description

Comment: Ah, of course... I omitted the fact that it was the desred result! In reality the 3 last columns are empty and I need to calculate them. That's the problem... let me rectify the question.